# Conditional Observable chaining in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, chaining

I am working in Angular 2, and I am making a series of async calls from a service. Some of the calls only need to be made conditionally in my call chain. 
My initial call chain looks like the following:

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
this.post().flatMap( () => this.put() ).flatMap( () => this.get() )..etc.
```

Then I need to conditionally attach additional async calls to my chain based on a variable array.

I'm using this kind of approach:

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
...flatMap( () => return this.additionalCallsFunction(callArray) )
.flatMap( () => this.finalPostRequest() ).subscribe(...)

additionalCallsFunction(callArray){
  if(callArray.length === 0) return Observable.empty()
  else { return this.get().concatMap( (res) => this.put(res).flatMap( () => { 
    callArray.removefirstItem()
    return this.additionalCallsFunction(callArray)
  }); 
}
```

I'm fairly new to Angular and Observables, so I'm not sure I'm approaching this correctly. Whether or not my additional Calls Array is empty or not I'm seeing my initial calls happen, but neither the additional calls, nor my final Post request ever goes through when my function returns. I'm also not seeing any errors in my console. I've tried replacing .empty() with .never(), but no change.

Any help/advice appreciated!

Comment: Since I don't really need the extra features provided  by Observables, I just decided to use the toPromise() method, and solved it using promises. Would be neat to know where I went wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation, and I finished with using `Observable.of(undefined)` instead of `Observable.empty()`. 
I don't know why, but `Observable.empty()` interrupts the chain.

Any further explanation is very appreciated.